# GIF not loading with the CodePen code available

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif, codepen

I wanted to try out the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code from the [CodePen URL](https://codepen.io/nayabsd/pen/zYyBJxe).

**HTML / CSS / JavaScript Files:**

```js
var gifElements = document.querySelectorAll("img.gif");

for (var e in gifElements) {
  var element = gifElements[e];

  if (element.nodeName == "IMG") {
    var supergif = new SuperGif({
      gif: element,
      progressbar_height: 0,
      auto_play: false
    });

    var controlElement = document.createElement("div");
    controlElement.className = "gifcontrol loading g" + e;

    supergif.load(
      function(controlElement) {
        controlElement.className = "gifcontrol paused";
        var playing = false;
        controlElement.addEventListener(
          "click",
          function() {
            if (playing) {
              this.pause();
              playing = false;
              controlElement.className = "gifcontrol paused";
            } else {
              this.play();
              playing = true;
              controlElement.className = "gifcontrol playing";
            }
          }.bind(this, controlElement)
        );
      }.bind(supergif)(controlElement)
    );

    var canvas = supergif.get_canvas();
    controlElement.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
    controlElement.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
    controlElement.style.left = canvas.offsetLeft + "px";
    var containerElement = canvas.parentNode;
    containerElement.appendChild(controlElement);
  }
}
```

```css
img.gif {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.jsgif {
  position: relative;
}

.gifcontrol {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:after {
    transition: background 0.25s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
  }
  &.loading {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    &:after {
      background: #ff9900;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }
  }
  &.playing {
    /* Only show the 'stop' button on hover */
    &:after {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
      border-left: 20px solid #ff9900;
      border-right: 20px solid #ff9900;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    &:hover:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  &.paused {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    &:after {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 25px 0 25px 50px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff9900;
    }
  }
  transition: background 0.25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/css/imgGif.css">
  <!-- Load imgGif.js -->
  <script src="/home/js/imgGif.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 600px; margin: auto; text-align: center; font-family: arial">
    <p>And so, the unwritten law of the internet, that any experiment involving video/images must involve cats in one way or another, reared its head again. When would the internet's fascination with cats come to an end? Never. The answer is "Never".</p>
    <img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/pop.h-cdn.co/assets/17/24/1497533116-not-dead.gif' class="gif" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`imgGif.js` has JavaScript code from the CodePen webpage and `imgGif.css` has the CSS code from the same page.

Somehow the GIF is not loading on the web page I have created. But in CodePen it is working fine.

Appretiated the help here pointing the mistake.

And also when I remove `class="gif"` form the `<img>` element, the gif loads. But the Play/pause functionality missing.

Thanks

Comment: The codepen is loading `https://solarisedesign.co.uk/_themes/solarise/js/libgif.js` are you?

Comment: No. I didn't. Could you point me where did you find that line..

Comment: Click `Settings` and then click `JS`

Comment: Ahh!! Thanks.. It's loading fine now.. Do you think I should delete this question here then?

Comment: BTW I would download the file and upload it to your server instead of using the file hosting by them. There are so many reasons why you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Got it. I uploaded it to github and using as raw. Downloaded too if that's gone for some reason